# Password Policy validation using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have implemented Spring Security v 3.1.1.RELEASE.

On the change password screen, i need to implement the password validation as per the password policy specified.

Policy Example: 
Must include a mix of alpha-numeric and upper and lower case characters. (A-Z, a-z, 0-9)

Is there any functionality available with Spring Security itself for validating or regex is the easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think not.  Spring security take care of password encoding and matching, but doesn't provide any user/password creation feature. So, no password policy.

You could do it yourself with a spring Validator and, as you said, a regex.